# Idiomatically iterating over a 2 (or higher) dimensional sequence in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Is there a 'proper' way to iterate over a two-dimensional sequence in Clojure? 
Suppose I had a list of lists of numbers, like this

```
 ((1 2 3)
  (4 5 6)
  (7 8 9))
```

and I wanted to generate a new list of lists with each number incremented by one. Is there an easy way to do this in Clojure without relying on nested maps or loop/recurs? I've been able to do it, but my solutions are ugly and I find them difficult to understand when I re-read them.

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always just use a list comprehension. I find myself using them quite often coming from an imperative background so I don't know how idiomatic it is. In your specific case, you can do:

```
(for [my-list my-matrix] (map inc my-list))
```

Comment: I'm going to accept this one, although the others are certainly valid responses. This just trikes me as the shortest and most readable.

Comment: It should be noted that `for` produces a lazy sequence, so it only "iterates" when the value is requested.

Answer (score 19):

What you describe is precisely what `clojure.walk` is for:

```
(def matrix [[1 2 3]
             [4 5 6]
             [7 8 9]])
(use 'clojure.walk :only [prewalk])
(prewalk #(if (number? %) (inc %) %) matrix)
=> [[2 3 4] [5 6 7] [8 9 10]]
```

Note 1: it is idiomatic to use vectors instead of parentheses for literal sequential collections.

Note 2: walk preserves type.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning Note 1 - I'm still a little iffy on when to use one or the other.

Comment: This answer is referenced by the Clojure cheat sheet at clojure.org.

Answer (score 11):

For the two-dimensional case, you could do something like:

```
(map #(map inc %) my-two-d-list)
```

That's not too bad to read:  apply the function `#(map inc %)` to each element in a list.

For the higher-order case, you're basically talking about tree-traversal.  You'd want a function that takes in a tree and a function, and applies that function to each node in the tree.  You can find functions for this in [clojure.walk](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.walk-api.html).

Answer (score 6):

The other answers by Sean and Matt both show concise and effective ways of getting the right result.

However there are some important extensions you can make to this:

- It would be nice to handle the case of higher dimensions
- It is good to wrap the functionality in a higher order function

Example code:

```
;; general higher order function
(defn map-dimensions [n f coll] 
  (if (= n 1)
    (map f coll)
    (map #(map-dimensions (dec n) f %) coll)))

;; use partial application to specialise to 2 dimensions
(def map-2d (partial map-dimensions 2))

(map-2d inc  
    '((1 2 3)
      (4 5 6)
      (7 8 9)))
=> ((2 3 4) (5 6 7) (8 9 10))
```

Comment: It's nevertheless valuable to see how it can be done from scratch.

Comment: Also, `prewalk` requires a function that distinguishes leaf nodes from branch nodes.  You can't just give `inc`, for example.

Answer (score 6):

Since the introduction of `core.matrix` in 2013, this is now a much better way of handling operations over multi-dimensional arrays:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix)

(def M  [[1 2 3]
         [4 5 6]
         [7 8 9]])

(emap inc M)

=> [[2 3 4 ]
    [5 6 7 ]
    [8 9 10]]
```

Advantages of using `core.matrix`:

- Clean, idiomatic Clojure code
- Lots of general purpose n-dimensional array manipulation functions - `transpose`, `shape`, `reshape`, `slice`, `subarray` etc.
- Ability to plug in high performance array implementations (e.g. for big numerical arrays)

Answer (score 1):

A belated answer, and maybe not exactly what is needed: you could try [flatten](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten). It will return a seq that you can iterate over:

```
(flatten  '((1 2 3)
            (4 5 6)
            (7 8 9)))

user=> (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)
```

And in order to increment matrix elements and reassemble the matrix:

```
(partition 3 (map inc (flatten  '((1 2 3)
                                  (4 5 6)
                                  (7 8 9)))))
```